# Run PHP script after Azure Web app deployment

Tags: php, curl, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am having an Azure app Service and I want to upload/deploy an .php file to it an run it right after the upload.

I managed to upload it via curl and also start a post deployment script. Unfortunately I can not use the command "php ..." in it because I get an error like: "/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh: line 2: exec: php: not found\n" in the logs.
The same occurs if I use the "/api/command" endpoint with the same command. I get the same kind of error in the response.

It seems like the php executable is not known in that environment.
Is there any way to run a php script via the command API or in a post deployment script?

EDIT for further clarification:
I need curl because I want to run it automatically with a deployer which generates a php file which then does our specific deployment tasks (generating folders, symlinks and so on). So after I deploy that php file on the App service I need to start it. So far curl was the only opportunity I found which doesn't need a user interaction if done correctly. With right after the upload I mean after using one of the 2 SCM/Kudu apis which are "/api/zip/" or "api/zipdeploy/"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "right after the upload"? Why do you need cURL for this?

Comment: I need curl because I want to run it automatically with a deployer which generates a php file which then does our specific deployment tasks (generating folders, symlinks and so on). So after I deploy that php file on the App service I need to start it. So far curl was the only opportunity i found which doesnt need a user interaction if done correctly.
With right after the upload i mean after using one of the 2 SCM/Kudu apis which are "/api/zip/" or "api/zipdeploy/

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use WebJob for running the scripts in Azure App Service Instance without any user interactions or which acts as background tasks.
- [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#overview) is to simplify many programming tasks.
- The file types (scripts or programs) supported by Azure WebJobs SDK are :
  **.cmd, .bat, .exe, .ps1, .sh *.php*, .py, .js, .jar**
- Just tweak your php script to have a loop and add a sleep of a few minutes between runs of your code.
- The continuous WebJob will run on all of your instances and even if something fails it will be brought back up.